# Git lfs not extending the size of files that I am able to push to github

Tags: javascript, html, css, git-lfs

I was trying to upload a file to git that is apparently 500 MB. I was told to try git lfs, but when I installed and set it up, I get this error:

remote: error: Trace: c287f1da79484f1e6e8f49fc71325ebeed8766e99945011efef8721ced1ddba0
remote: error: See https://gh.io/lfs for more information.
remote: error: File mainPage/img/tempPost.mp4 is 541.34 MB; this exceeds GitHub's file size limit of 100.00 MB
remote: error: GH001: Large files detected. You may want to try Git Large File Storage - https://git-lfs.github.com.

Even if 500 is above the limit, the previous limit of 100mb did not change once I installed git lfs and set it to track mp4 files. Not sure what the problem is, and youtube/internet is not helping that much. Any ideas?